# Почему я не могу редактировать файлы в админке modx?

Tags: php, modx

На локальном сервере установлена modx revolution версии 2.4.2.

В файловом менеджере не открываются файлы на редактирование (даже через быстрое редактирование).

В журнале ошибок пусто. В консоли ошибка:

> "Cannot read property 'style' of undefined" в файле ext-all.js.

Сжатие js в админке выключено. Установлены дополнения: modxSite, modxSDK, phpTemplates, modxSmarty.

Может быть, работа какого-либо из дополнений влияет?

Открываю modxSDK - не отображается содержимое шаблонов

Comment: Скорей всего, прав на запись этих файлов нет у аккаунта в контексте которого исполняется php.

Comment: Работаю под уч. записью администратора. Должна быть запись

Comment: нет разницы под кем вы работаете. Важно "под кем работает php"

Comment: Нашёл ту же, что и у меня, тему: https://modx.ru/vopros-otvet/info/2540/. Скачал test_config.php в корень сайта - те же ошибки, что и в статье. Залил файлы modx 2.4.1 поверх имеющихся, провёл обновление через установку - ничего не изменилось, файлы так же нельзя редактировать.